# Visual Studio Code kills wayland session

Tags: gnome, snap, wayland

I have an Ubuntu 18.10 and installed VSCode via snap.
When I'm logged in into a Wayland session and try to start VSCode (run `vscode`) I get logged out.
When I use X11, everything works fine.

Does anybody have an idea what might be the problem or could give me an advice how to debug such a problem?

Comment: Do you get any information from `/var/log/syslog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.
It's a duplicate of https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61074